# Can't make an omelette in my all-clad pan because of sticking

Tags: aluminum-cookware

I have an all-clad pan that I have used many times for scrambling eggs. Usually there is no issue with sticking. Recently, I've tried to make an omelette in the pan by sautée-ing the vegetables first. Afterwards, I pour on the eggs. I've found that if the eggs go under the vegetables, it will stick to the pan. Any way to get around this?

Comment: Does all-clad really have aluminium pans? I thought that they generally make steel pans, some of them with cores.

Answer (score 2):

It also happens to me sometimes, what I suggest you do is spread oil uniformly on the pan and make sure you pour the egg in the middle of the pan. If the pan has oil on all sides it does not matter if you add the vegetables first or later as topping on  the egg.

There is also a way out, pour the egg first, adjust flame of the burner to low
and add the vegetables on the egg. As the base gets hard enough that you can turn it on the pan, do it quickly and cook the vegetables attached with the half cooked omelette. Then enjoy eating the omelette...

Answer (score 1):

Moving the vegetables around is going to disrupt the uniformity of the layer of oil on the pan, which you are going to need for something like an omelette in an aluminum pan.  Or even just having the vegetables there, probably absorbing some of the oil and releasing water, is going to do the same.

You will probably have to saute the vegetables separately, and add them in later, instead of the method you are using now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience. Now, I do exactly as you do, but with one difference. After I sauté the veg, I remove it from the pan, add a pat of butter (or a slick of oil) and swirl to recoat the bottom and sides of the pan. I pour in the whipped eggs, give the pan quite a few hard shakes to aerate the eggs, and then add the saued vegetables.